# Using OPTIONAL and UNION in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, linked-data

I want to write a query to fetch triples about entities related to a film. This is the query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 WHERE {

SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql/> {

?film ?p ?o
FILTER (?film = :Braveheart) .

OPTIONAL {
{
{
{?o ?p2 ?o2 .}
OPTIONAL {
  {?o2 ?p21 ?o21}
  UNION
  {?s21 ?p22 ?o2}
}
}

UNION

{?s1 ?p3 ?o}
}
}
}
}
```

This query does not fetch results. However, commenting the section

```
OPTIONAL {
  {?o2 ?p21 ?o21}
  UNION
  {?s21 ?p22 ?o2}
}
```

generates the results. I want to understand why the `OPTIONAL` clause prevents the results from being generated and how I can resolve the issue.

Comment: There is a timeout in the web interface which makes use of the Virtuoso anytime feature.

Answer (score 2):

Try (note: timeout in original query was due to Cartesian product arising from placement of OPTIONAL CLAUSE.) :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s1  WHERE 
  {
    dbr:Braveheart ?p ?o
    OPTIONAL 
      {
        {
          {?s1 ?p3 ?o}
          UNION
          {
            {?o ?p2 ?o2 }
            OPTIONAL 
              {
                {?o2 ?p21 ?o21}
                UNION
                {?s21 ?p22 ?o2}
              }
          }
        }
      } 
  }
```

Links:

- [Live Query Definition Link in DBpedia Query Editor](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs1%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbr%3ABraveheart%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fs1%20%3Fp3%20%3Fo%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fo%20%3Fp2%20%3Fo2%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fo2%20%3Fp21%20%3Fo21%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fs21%20%3Fp22%20%3Fo2%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)
- [Live Query Results Page from DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fs1%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbr%3ABraveheart%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fs1%20%3Fp3%20%3Fo%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fo%20%3Fp2%20%3Fo2%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fo2%20%3Fp21%20%3Fo21%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%3Fs21%20%3Fp22%20%3Fo2%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where did you pose this query (I assume Sparql endpoint)  and what does it mean does not fetch any results but I have written the query a little bit simpler as following and executed on the endpoint:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s1 WHERE {
dbr:Braveheart ?p ?o
    OPTIONAL {
    {
        {
            {?o ?p2 ?o2 .}
            OPTIONAL {
              {?o2 ?p21 ?o21}
              UNION
              {?s21 ?p22 ?o2}
            }
        }
       UNION
       {?s1 ?p3 ?o}
    }
   } 
  }
```

It does not return results because of the time out. Otherwise, there is no problem with the OPTIONAL clause. For example, if you put "dbo:narrator" instead of "?p" you will see the results.